# on-the-fly compressed volumes for Windows

Tags: file-compression

I am looking for a freeware Windows tool that provides on-the-fly compressed virtual drives stored in files (similar to TrueCrypt disks).

The virtual drive should offer **random access** and should be **writable**, so  [Prismo CFS](http://pismotec.com/pfm/) is not an option.

I've tried [WIM images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Imaging_Format) in the past but they require a lot of free memory to mount and update.

Comment: Would a container that supports NTFS and then use ntfs compression one the file work?

Comment: I've considered NTFS compression as well, but it [causes a lot of fragmentation](https://superuser.com/questions/693275/avoiding-extreme-fragmentation-of-compressed-system-images-on-ntfs) and it is not usable on optical disks for backups.

Comment: I was thinking a VHD file with NTFS compression on the inside.